# How can you trap TurtleGraphicsError with a 'try' statement

Tags: graphics, exception, turtle-graphics

If in Python's Turtle Graphics you enter a color that is not recognised, the system comes back at you with, for instance:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\turtle\ex21-starafterstar.py", line 18, in <module>
    color(outline,fillcol)      # Set pen and fill colors
  File "<string>", line 1, in color
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2208, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2688, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 1150, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: yucky brown
```

From this, one might deduce that the way to trap such errors in a 'try statement is to code:

```
try:
    outline = input("Enter the outline color  > ")
    pencolor(outline)
    break
except TurtleGraphicsError:
    print("Sorry. I don't recognise that color.")
```

But that doesn't work. It generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/turtle/ex28-star5coloredtry.py", line 17, in <module>
    except TurtleGraphicsError:
NameError: name 'TurtleGraphicsError' is not defined
```

My question therefore is, what is the name of the error class for Turtle Graphics errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, the name `TurtleGraphicsError` is not defined in that scope. It is defined inside the `turtle` package. You can either import it like:

```
from turtle import TurtleGraphicsError
```

or use it's qualified name

```
import turtle
try:
    ...
except turtle.TurtleGraphicsError:
    print(...)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, shx2, but neither of your solutions works! Have you actually tried and tested these?

Comment: Hang on. It's ok. You have to actually import turtle rather than 'from turtle import TurtleGraphicsError'. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnofYork I took it for granted you already had a `import turtle` line. Edited my answer